# Why does Drupal still convert links using a non-existant url alias pattern

Tags: 7, views, caching, path-aliases

First I created an alias for an entity type like this:

```
project/[project_type]/[id]
```

which worked fine. After a while I decided to delete all aliases and created a new pattern, and bulk generated all aliases.

```
[project_type]/[id]
```

However, drupal still converts menu links (with internal path) as well as links in views (linkto content) using the old pattern project/[project_type]/[id]

- I have cleared cache of the site,
- I have cleared the views cache,
- I have re-saved all entities, I have checked the alias list, the
  aliases pattern that drupal uses is not present in the list, the new alias patterns are present.

In some way, drupal still uses this phantom-pattern which is cached somewhere apparently. It refuses to use the new alias pattern for converting links.

The new alias patterns do work for manually created links that correspond with the new pattern. Just the automatic conversion from internal path to alias path does not work, it does use the new alias but an already deleted alias.

Comment: Drupal entities preserve the alias they have, also when you resave the entity. You need to regenerate all the aliases. As Anisur explains below, you can try to change the update action. Personally, I have once chosen to bulk delete all existing aliases and directly regenerate them again for all content types. That works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases (settings tab)

```
Update action
 Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.
 Create a new alias. Leave the existing alias functioning.
 Create a new alias. Delete the old alias.
```